# Aws EC2 machine don't have enough disk space

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, aws-cloudformation

When I create ec2 machine I choose disk size 30GB and another is 40Gb, but when I remote into this machine disk size only 16GB. Does anyone how to increase this

Size in AWS:
[image]

Size when I remote into it and check by command: `df -h --total`
[image]

Thank all!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article that describes just that:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

You need to mount the EBS volumes that are not mounted. Based on the screenshot you provided, it looks like your root volume is 8GiB and you added 2 additional EBS volumes of 30GiB and 40GiB.

Use `lsblk` to determine if your volumes are mounted or not. Most probably they are not mounted. Follow the instructions in the article and you will be good.

Answer (score 0):

From the Amazon EC2 console -> choose the volume listed for Block devices -> Choose the EBS ID -> Modify Volume -> choose Volume Type -> enter the Size -> choose Modify -> Save

The expanded volume is immediately available for the OS.

Note: Windows root volumes can be extended up to 2 TB.

RDP into the instance -> launch the Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc) -> Action -> Refresh -> context (right-click) menu -> choose Extend Volume -> Next -> Finish.